# Quote Symbol Expected in JSP

Tags: jsp

I cannot figure out what I am missing. I am getting a quote symbol expected in my JSP for this line:

```
var newField = "<form:input type=\"text\" path=\"hobbies["+nextHobbyIndex+"]\"/>";

newHobbyIndex is a javascript variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different codes. The key is to realize, **where** and **when** each code is executed - JSP on the server when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is send to the browser) and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response.

In this case, the `<form:input type=\"text\" ...` will be processed on the server side, thus `type=\"text\"` should be `type="text"` etc.